# Inner joins in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to select values from 3 tables and i am using inner join for that, i am using following query

```
  SELECT 
    UserDetail.UserId 'userId', 
    FirstName  'name',  
    Name 'role' 
    FROM UserDetail as ud 
       inner join UserRole as ur ON ud.UserId = ur.UserId 
       inner join [Role] as r ON r.RoleId=ur.RoleId 
       WHERE Username = @username and [Password] =@password
```

It is showing me following error:  multi part identifier UserId could not be bound(UserDetail.UserId). can anybody tell me what wrong i am doing. thanks

Comment: Does the UserDetail table have the column UserId?

Comment: @user2575061 Please mark an answer which is helpful to you, to close this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `UserDetail.UserId` with `ud.UserId`. If you're using an alias (`UserDetail as ud`) in the `FROM` clause you have to use that same alias everywhere else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `UserDetail.UserId` with `ud.UserId`

**i.e.:**

```
SELECT 
    ud.UserId 'userId', 
    FirstName  'name',  
    Name 'role' 
    FROM UserDetail as ud 
       inner join UserRole as ur ON ud.UserId = ur.UserId 
       inner join [Role] as r ON r.RoleId=ur.RoleId 
       WHERE Username = @username and [Password] =@password
```